# What does "idiot-proof-ness" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm looking specifically for the meaning in this sentence:

> But I would say the biggest advantage of Optional syntax in Java isn't in readability: the advantage is its idiot-proof-ness.

Comment: Idiot-proof 
adj. Slang:
Made or designed to be used or operated with very little risk of breakage or failure: "These point-and-shoot cameras are almost idiot-proof" (Donald H. Dunn).

Comment: "If you make something idiot proof, someone will just make a better idiot."

Comment: ... so _idiot-proof-ness_ means sturdiness/toughness in the sense of resistance to (i.e., ability to resist or avoid) bad outcomes from improper use.

Comment: _Idiot-proof_ is essentially the same word as _foolproof_, leading to the line, "It is impossible to make anything foolproof because fools are so ingenious." which is sometimes considered to be one of [Murphy's Laws](http://www.std.com/obi/alt.quotations/Archive/murphy.txt). (Thanks, @Dan, for reminding me of this.)

Answer (score 7):

The suffix *-proof* added to something means "*can't be harmed by*"

If it's waterproof it can't be harmed by water. If it's fireproof it can't be harmed by fire.  If it's idiot-proof it can't be harmed by idiots.

The suffix *-ness* is used to reference the quality or characteristic of being something.  If I talk about something's *"fireproof-ness"* I'm talking about the thing's quality of being fireproof.

Idiot-proof-ness therefore refers to a thing's quality or characteristic of being incapable of being harmed by an idiot.

In this specific case it's saying Java's Optional syntax is hard to mess up.

Comment: "-ness" turns an adjective into a noun.

Comment: It should be noted that the "word" `idiot-proof-ness` was probably written somewhat humorously: It's such a cobbled together non-word that it's amusing. But the point still gets across to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

"Idiot-proof-ness" pretty much means people that are idiots can't mess up with the said object.

> "The new phones are equipped with metal coating and are completely idiot-proof".

This shows that the new phones have metal coating and idiots will not be able to be mess up with it (drop it).

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that the object in question has a characteristic such that "it's so easy even an idiot will not fail when using it"

It has nothing to do with a capability of not breaking when tampered with by an idiot, by the way

Answer (score -1):

A possibly synonym for idiot-proofness that is often used in programming is robustness.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_(computer_science)

Comment: Some citations or examples to show the usage of robustness as your choice would help substantiate your answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, I realize most people probably don't use it as much as I do.